# Find duplicate text in a row with formula in excel

Tags: excel, text, duplicates, row

I have a spreadsheet and I need to find duplicate names in a row and flag it up in the cell starting that row, as well as that some names will be followed by a third word, so the formula will need to only look at the first 2 words in the cell. In the below example each item is a cell in a row:

Duplicate found, Jim Table, Felix Laptop, Tommy Window, Jim Table (Science), Donny Foot

The first cell has highlighted the duplicate "Jim Table" even though the second occurrence has "(Science)" on the end. What formula could I use for this?

I tried the below but it only seems to work with numbers.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$7:$Z$7,MODE($D$7:$Z$7))>1,"List has duplicates","No duplicates")
```

I really want to avoid making a UDF as it will be used by many users on separate computers.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to have a look. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this version

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(D7:Z7,LEFT(D7:Z7,FIND(" ",D7:Z7&" ",FIND(" ",D7:Z7)+1)-1)&"*")>1)+0),"List has duplicates","No duplicates")`

The `COUNTIF` criteria part with `LEFT/FIND/FIND` finds the first two words of each cell, so if those repeat anywhere the `COUNTIF` returns a number >1 and `SUMPRODUCT` returns a positive, triggering the "List has duplicates" message

Comment: That is actually amazing! thank you for the gift of time, who knows how many hours of pain you have spared me from. I'm going to get my girlfriend to call me Barry in your honor for the remainder of the evening....fanbloomingtastic!!!!!

Comment: Hey! now that's what I call a compliment! You are welcome - if you want you can use "Barry" for the rest of the week...